# Is it good practice to send status data using Http Post?

Tags: rest, http

I know post is usually used to tell the web server to store stuff, what is the right way to do if I just want to send some status data?  Say, I'm posting a client status?

Comment: If you're updating the state of a "client" object, you might use PUT.  If you're create a new "client status" object, you might use POST.

Comment: Can you please clarify "client status".

Comment: I mean just a arbitrary status from the client app that i need to notify the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to update the state of an existing resource, you must use the `PUT` method. But the latter corresponds to the update of the whole state, i.e. you need to send all fields. If you want to do a partial update, you should consider the `PATCH` one. You can send only the field or leverage the [JSON Patch](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902) format.

Here are some samples:

- Full update:

  ```
    PUT /someresource/someid
    Content-Type: application/json
    {
      (...)
      "status": "some status"
    }
  ```
- partial update:

  ```
    PATCH /someresource/someid
    Content-Type: application/json
    {
      "status": "some status"
    }

    204 No content
  ```
- partial update with JSON Patch:

  ```
    PATCH /someresource/someid
    Content-Type: application/json
    [
      {
        "op": "replace",
        "path": "/status",
        "value": "some status"
      }
    ]

    204 No content
  ```

If "send some status data" corresponds to add something in your datastore, you should consider to use a `POST` method but on the list resource (single resource is used for `PUT` and `PATCH` for a specific resource element). Here is a sample:

```
    PUT /someresource/
    Content-Type: application/json
    {
      (...)
      "status": "some status"
    }

    204 No content
    Location: http://.../someresource/newid
```

Here are some additional links that could help you:

- **Designing a Web API (i.e. RESTful service)**: http://restlet.com/blog/2015/03/16/designing-a-web-api/
- **Don't patch like an idiot**: http://williamdurand.fr/2014/02/14/please-do-not-patch-like-an-idiot/

Hope it will help you,
Thierry

Answer (score 1):

If you are not updating anything then POST is the method you should use it.

Comment: I thought a post was also to used if you want to update something.  or do you mean to use Patch for updates?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your use case. In a strict rest environment thierry's answer is correct. However, when I use rest everyday towards financial services I must save all data without any changes according to law (e.g. traceability). In my case I cannot use strict rest so I use POST with the whole object with one or more changes to its attributes. The server responds with "201 Created" and a proper status message since every new request is a new resource.